# Check if object member exists in nested object

Tags: javascript, object

Is there a simpler way than using `___ in object` to check the existence of each level of an object to check the existence of a single member?

More concisely: How can I check if **someObject.member.member.member.value** exists?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In general, you can use `if(property in object)`, but this would be still cumbersome for nested members.

You could write a function:

```
function test(obj, prop) {
    var parts = prop.split('.');
    for(var i = 0, l = parts.length; i < l; i++) {
        var part = parts[i];
        if(obj !== null && typeof obj === "object" && part in obj) {
            obj = obj[part];
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

test(someObject, 'member.member.member.value');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7nPnz/3/)

Comment: Looks good. I like the looping approach, but how does the __typeof obj === "object"__ help exactly? Isn't it true that typeof can return object for null and array too?

Comment: @JustcallmeDrago: True... would not matter so much for the array though, but it would fail for `null`. So it is maybe better to add a check for null as well. I added the test because `'value' in <primitive type>` would throw an error. Added `null` test.

Comment: @Felix: I see. I really like the string as an argument, but also the simplicity of Patrick's answer. Is his as safe as yours? Is it as fast?

Comment: @JustcallmeDrago: His is probably faster. But you would have problems with the last value. The result of his code is either `undefined` or the value of the last property. If this is set to `undefined` the you cannot distinguish. But assuming that you never set a value like that, it should be save. Honestly, I find it a bit harder to read though, and if you want to make reusable you'd have loops again... but both will work.

Comment: I think I'll do some sort of check like his, but use a loop like yours. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Felix: I think I've got it. Would you look this over? http://jsfiddle.net/7nPnz/4/

Comment: @JustcallmeDrago: Looks ok to me. I would just replace the regular expression search with `indexOf('.')`. And I'm not sure but I guess that the recursion is slower in general.

Comment: It would be nice if this also supported array notation like `test(someObject, 'member['member'].member[3].value');`. I'm wondering if this is a corner case for using `eval`.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt but... somebody here mentioned "Patrick's answer" as being faster. Err... where is this answer? :-?

Comment: The only solution that works for me! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You could also try/catch TypeError?

```
try {
  console.log(someObject.member.member.member.value);
} catch(e) {
  if (e instanceof TypeError) {
    console.log("Couldn't access someObject.member.member.member.value");
    console.log(someObject);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way: http://jsfiddle.net/9McHq/

```
var result = ((((someObject || {}).member || {}).member || {}).member || {}).value;

alert( result );
```

Comment: Nice. Surely this can be turned into a recursive function pretty easily!

Answer (score 3):

Check out lodash-deep’s `deepHas` https://github.com/marklagendijk/lodash-deep#_deephascollection-propertypath

And this too https://github.com/danielstjules/hoops

Answer (score 2):

Something like (warning: untested code ahead)

```
var testProperty = function(obj, proplist) {
   for (var i=0; i < proplist.length; i++) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(proplist[i])) {
         obj = obj[proplist[i]];
      } else {
        return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: @Felix -- thanks, fixed.  Also, see Phrogz's answer for an alternative to hasOwnProperty

Comment: See the comment to my answer, yours would also fail if `obj` is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (someObject.member && someObject.member.member &&
    someObject.member.member.member && someObject.member.member.member.value) ...
```

or similarly:

```
var val = foo.bar && foo.bar.jim && foo.bar.jim.jam && foo.bar.jim.jam.value;
```

This will not 'work' if any particular value happens to be `null`, `false`, `0`, or `""` (an empty string), but with the possible exception of the final value, this seems unlikely to be the case.

Also, note that `typeof ____ !== "undefined"` is not the correct test to see if an object has a property. Instead you should use `___ in object`, e.g. `if ("member" in someObject)`. This is because you can set a property to an explicit value of `undefined`, which is different from removing it with `delete someObject.member`.

Answer (score 2):

Theres a safeRead function defined [here on thecodeabode](http://thecodeabode.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/javascript-safely-reading-nested.html) which allows a safeRead of nested properties
i.e.

```
safeRead(foo, 'bar', 'jim', 'jam');
```

if any of the properties are null or undefined a blank string is returned - useful for formatting / string interpolation

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `lodash` library, it has a very elegant solution, **[hasIn](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2#hasIn)**.

```
_.hasIn(someObject, 'member.level1.level2.level3');
```

for example,

```
var obj = {'x': 999, 'a': {'b': {'c': 123, 'd': 234}}}
// => undefined

_.hasIn(obj, 'x')
// => true

_.hasIn(obj, 'a.b.d')
// => true

_.hasIn(obj, 'a.b.e')
// => false
```