# How to check if a variable inside an object that's inside another object is set (js)?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to do this:

```
if(a.b.c) alert('c exists')   //produces error
if(a && a.b && a.b.c ) alert('c exists')   //also produces ReferenceError
```

The only way I know of to do this (EDIT: This apparently is the only way):

```
if(typeof(a) != "undefined" && a.b && a.b.c) alert('c exists');
```

or some type of function like this...

```
if(exists('a.b.c')) alert('c exists');
function exists(varname){
    vars=varname.split('.');
    for(i=0;i<vars.length;i++){
       //iterate through each object and check typeof
    }
}
//this wont work with local variables inside a function
```

**EDIT: SOLUTION BELOW**
(Credit to this thread by Felix, I just adapted it a little
 [Check if object member exists in nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676223/check-if-object-member-exists-in-nested-object))

This works:

```
if (typeof a != 'undefined' && a.b && a.b.c) alert('c exists')
```

But the best thing I found is to put it into a function. I use 2 different functions, one to get a variable deep in an object, and one just to check if its set.

```
/**
 * Safely retrieve a property deep in an object of objects/arrays
 * such as userObj.contact.email
 * @usage var email=getprop(userObj, 'contact.email')
 *      This would retrieve userObj.contact.email, or return FALSE without
 *      throwing an error, if userObj or contact obj did not exist
 * @param obj OBJECT - the base object from which to retrieve the property out of
 * @param path_string STRING - a string of dot notation of the property relative to
 * @return MIXED - value of obj.eval(path_string), OR FALSE
 */
function getprop(obj, path_string)
{
    if(!path_string) return obj
    var arr = path_string.split('.'),
        val = obj || window;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        val = val[arr[i]];
        if ( typeof val == 'undefined' ) return false;
        if ( i==arr.length-1 ) {
            if (val=="") return false
            return val
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Check if a proprety on an object exists
 * @return BOOL
 */
function isset(obj, path_string)
{
    return (( getprop(obj, path_string) === false ) ? false : true)
}
```

Comment: No, the custom function is the best you can get. I think I already answered a similar question, but I cannot find it ;)

Comment: Just a side note, typeof is not a function, so you don't need the parens. You can just say  `if (typeof a !== 'undefined' && ...`

Comment: What is your code doing trying to access the interstices of a variable when you don't even know that the variable exists.  Quite apart from contravention of the Law of Demeter, it seems dubious to me (a non-Javascript programmer) to be trying to access the variable in the first place.

Comment: `x.y` <-- `y` is a *property* of the object stored in `x`. That is, `y` is not a *variable*. *Variables* can only be accessed by their name in the applicable lexical scope.

Comment: The "ReferenceError" occurs because the variable `a` is not defined (nor is it a property of the global [`window`] object). "Declare" it with `var` first and/or assign it a value (if you just assign a value a new window property -- global -- will be created if needed). All the answers below are correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if object member exists in nested object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676223/check-if-object-member-exists-in-nested-object)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - if for exmaple, a json object is coming back from an ajax call... such as userObj.contact.home_phone. The user may or may not have set a home_phone...

Comment: Note that the function above can be augmented to address bracket access (e.g. `a.b[3]` or `a.b[c]` ) as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
function exists(str, namespace) {
    var arr = str.split('.'),
        val = namespace || window;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        val = val[arr[i]];
        if ( typeof val == 'undefined' ) return false;
    }
    return true;    
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Y3KRd/

Comment: Thanks for working this out for me. i was hoping to avoid this, but I guess its the only way.

Comment: Depending on your use, you should also balance code structure with performance. Whilst verbose, the typeof operator is fast.

Comment: @timh My solution does not work well. If, for instance, you call the exists() function from inside a function context, then you won't be able to evaluate the local variables of that function (unless you are able to pass the local namespace into the exists() function). See here: http://jsfiddle.net/MdWEH/

Comment: ha. yea i was just going to mention that. im not sure how to pass a local functions namespace into the variable... any ideas?

Comment: @timh I don't think that's possible. If I remember correctly, the local namespace of a function is represented by the function's Variable object which cannot be accessed programmatically.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
if (a && a.b && a.b.c)
```

Comment: try it. im doing it in chrome now:

    `if (a && a.b && a.b.c) alert(1)
    ReferenceError: a is not defined`

THIS works... but still annoying: `if (typeof(a)!="undefined" && a.b && a.b.c) alert(1)`

Comment: Where is `a` coming from? Joel's code is legit and should work.

Comment: assume for this example, its a global variable. but remember since im testing if a.b.c exists, it could very well be that "a" doesnt even exist in the first place. EDIT: just tested a local variable in a function scope and got same result.

Comment: @timh The assumption is wrong -- the ReferenceError occurs because it is *not* a property on the window object as is *not* a variable. Fix that. Either that or some *other* code is throwing the error.

Comment: @timh It does. **Your assumptions are incorrect.** `var a = "it works"; if (a && a.length) { alert(a) }`

Comment: This solution would prevent you passing any value that evaluates to false, such as null, 0 etc.  The typeof operator should be used, either directly or encapsulated into another function.

Comment: True. this is not the correct solution. I edited it, but someone edited it back, so I will post it into my original answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

How about double-banging the evaluation?

```
if (!!a && !!a.b && !!a.b.c)
```

Comment: Sorry Reid, but that's not true. Just run `!!undefined` from a console and you will see it return `false`.

Comment: Try running !!xyz, and you dont get false, you get error. I just ran the "if" statement you suggested in chrome js console on ubuntu, and got ReferenceError also "a is not defined"

Comment: The problem isn't with the `.b` or `.b.c` it is with the `a`. Property-access can return undefined, but will *never* throw an error (unless overloaded).

Comment: @timh Because **a is not defined** Try: `var a = 1; if (a && a.b && a.b.c) { .. }` Note that there *is* an `a` defined in that snippet.

Comment: right but that defeats the purpose doesnt it? That would overwrite my variable a, if it existed.

Comment: @timh *Don't use* a variable (or "global variable") you *don't have*. Statically typed languages would trigger this error at compile-time. If you may-or-may not have it: `window.a && window.a.b ...` Note that now `a` is accessed *as a property*.

Comment: @pst ok I got you. but even so... doing the whole (a && a.b && a.b.c) is annoying, but if I must then ok. The 2nd question with the exists() function I guess would be the best solution assuming I didn't want to didn't want to hassle with the .. && .. && .. method.