# What is a concise way to deep test an object hasOwnProperty (or the like)?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I need to do something with an object. Unfortunately the system I'm doing this with (Titanium) expects values to be non-null, otherwise it will segfault. The input, however, cannot be guaranteed to provide sane objects. Here is an example:

```
var data = {
  foo: {
    bar: "foobar"
  }
};
function do_it(data) {
  do_something_with_non_null_value(data.foo.bar);
}
```

However it is entirely possible that `data` is any of the following:

```
var data = null;
var data = {
  foo: null
};
var data = {
  foo: {
    bar: null
  }
};
```

How can I test for a non-null value in a deep but concise manor to prevent the `do_something_with_non_null_value()` from crashing?

Underscore.js answers are also welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676223/check-if-object-member-exists-in-nested-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `defaults` method from underscore?

```
function do_it(data) {

  var defaults = {
    foo: {
      bar: null
    }
  };

  data = _.defaults(data || {}, defaults);

  do_something_with_non_null_value(data.foo.bar);
}
```

If data is any of this:

```
var data = null;
var data = {
  foo: null
};
```

Will change the object to:

```
var data = {
  foo: {
    bar: null
  }
};
```

Comment: Well this won't help the case when data is more then 3 levels deep. It does fit the bill in regards to the question. Well done.