# A simple way to see if a complex object variable (objectVar.some.other.value) is defined

Tags: javascript, object, scope

My code is getting really quite polluted with:

```
if( typeof( objectVar ) === 'object' && objectVar !== 'null' )
  if( typeof( objectVar.other ) === 'object' && objectVar.other !== 'null' )
     // OK, objectVar.other is an object, yay!
   }
 }
```

This is a little ridiculous. I am after a function that reads like this:

```
isProperObject( objectVar.other );
```

Considering that if `objectVar` is not defined, this will actually fail miserably, maybe I should do instead:

```
isProperObject( 'objectVar.other' );
```

Then the function could `eval()` it. But no! It cannot do that, because `isProperObject()` would be in a different scope, one without `objectVar`.

So, it could be:

```
isProperObject( objectVar, 'other' )
```

OK this could work. Is there a function like this that is actually commonly used?

Comment: You can create one of your own, look  through the props and go on, once you find a part undefined return false.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if object member exists in nested object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676223/check-if-object-member-exists-in-nested-object)

Answer (score 1):

Your checks are needlessly verbose. You can do this instead:

```
if (objectVar != null && objectVar.other != null) {
   // OK, objectVar.other is an object, yay!
}
```

This will check for both `null` and `undefined`, and so gives you the safety you need.

Or if you really need `.other` to be an object:

```
if (objectVar && typeof objectVar.other === "object") {
   // OK, objectVar.other is an object, yay!
}
```

Also, you should have been testing for:

```
!== null
```

instead of:

```
!== 'null'
```

---

A different, novel approach is this:

```
if((objectVar || {}).other != null) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Move to a "higher level" of programming and initialize values to a *null or empty object*.

You should be working with top- and intermediate-level objects which are initialized to usable values, and you thus know to exist. Only the "leaf" objects should potentially be in empty/ null state.

For example, instead of:

```
var dialogTitle;
var dialogId;
var dialogElement;
```

Prefer to build a valid container object, in an "empty" state.

```
var dialog = {
    title: null,
    id: null,
    element: null
};
```

You can also use `if (dialog.id != null)` or, when you're not expecting `false` or `0` values, `if (dialog.id)`.