# Better way to see if an object has another object and a property

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I have this method. Is there a way to write it better? What I want to check if he trigger of analyticsTracker is available.

```
isTriggerAvailable: function() {
      return (
        typeof VC !== 'undefined' &&
        typeof VC.components !== 'undefined' &&
        typeof VC.components.analyticsTracker !== 'undefined' &&
        typeof VC.components.analyticsTracker.trigger !== 'undefined'
      );
    },
```

Comment: ok, I see that is a duplicate. What should I do? Delete it?

Comment: Leave it and it will probably get closed by the community, leaving it for others to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function described here.

```
  function checkNested(obj /*, level1, level2, ... levelN*/) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        obj = args.shift();

    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(args[i])) {
        return false;
      }
      obj = obj[args[i]];
    }
    return true;
  }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4676258/2134720